# Using FtpWebResponse to download file - file downloads even after removed from ftp server?

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am downloading a file from an ftp server using FtpWebResponse.  My code looks like this:

```
FtpWebRequest request;
try
{
    request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(path);
    request.UseBinary = true; 
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, passwd);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (Stream rs = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream())                         
        {
            rs.CopyTo(ms);          
        }         
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ... error handling code here ...
}
```

Which worked fine - I was able to read the memory stream and see the file.  I was testing, so I copied another file to the ftp server, deleted the old one, and renamed the new one to the same name, then re-ran my program.  I was still seeing the old file - the one I had deleted from the ftp server - not the new one.  So I deleted the new file - now there are no files on the ftp server.  I re-run my program, and it runs without error and continues to show me the original file from the ftp server.  If I ftp directly to the ftp server I verify that there are no files there...

What's happening?  Is the connection cached? These symptoms have been evident for an hour or so now...

Comment: Try `request.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);`

Comment: That fixed it - thanks.  Gotta love this forum.  I can't vote for your answer...

Comment: There, I added it as an answer.  Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
request.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNo‌​Store);
```